# Can't import other files into client.js with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, import, client

I have a react.js project. I use react-360 to generate a 360-degree look. I want to import data from firebase into my client.js. The data lies in my file firebaseData.js. So when I try to import it with

```
import * as firebaseData from 'firebaseData/firebaseData.js'
```

My whole app crashes. Any suggestions? The path should be just fine.

---

my firebase.js file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
  apiKey: 'xy',
  authDomain: 'xy',
  databaseURL: 'xy',
  projectId: 'xy',
  storageBucket: 'xy.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'xy'
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

export class firebaseData extends Component {

constructor () {
super()
this.state = {
  img: 0
}

  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('root')
    const dataRef = dbRef.child('value')


    dataRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        img: snap.val()
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with you want to "import data"?

Comment: basically the images are stored in firebase. The connection and everything is already working. Only the import of the firebase file (or just any other file in my project) into the client.js is not working

Comment: Can you post your `firebaseDate.js` file?

Comment: Posted it in the answers

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: 1. GET http://localhost:8081/client.bundle?platform=vr net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error) 
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: React360 is not defined
    at index.html:17

Answer (score 0):

import * as firebaseData from 'firebaseData/firebaseData.js'

Change to

import {firebaseData} from '. /firebaseData/firebaseData.js'

You need to add curly braces since it's not a default export and add a dot for the path.

I hope the firebaseData folder is inside the current dir.

I hope this will solve the issue. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it doesnt work.. Uncaught Error: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at NativeModules.js:127
    at loadModuleImplementation (require.js:178)
    at guardedLoadModule (require.js:130)
    at _require (require.js:110)
    at InitializeCore.js:119
    at loadModuleImplementation (require.js:178)
    at guardedLoadModule (require.js:123)
    at _require (require.js:110)
    at client.bundle?platform=vr:144215